# HashMap<String, List<String>> may not contain objects of type 'integer'

Tags: java, android, sqlite, hashmap, expandablelistview

I have written the code for displaying an ExpandableListView on android studio.
This is the code for the ExplandableListView:

```
public class Recipes extends AppCompatActivity implementsView.OnClickListener           {
ExpandableListView exp;
EditText t;
Button b;


HashMap<String, List<String>> Movies_category;
List<String> Movies_list;
ExpandableListView Exp_list;
MoviesAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.NoActionBar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes);
    t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes);
    Exp_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
    Movies_category = DataProvider.getInfo();
    Movies_list = new ArrayList<String>(Movies_category.keySet());
    adapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, Movies_category, Movies_list);
    Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    t.setOnClickListener(this);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Choose.class));
    }
}
```

And this for the methods to perform operations:

```
public class RecipeAda extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
private Context ctx;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> recipes;
private List<String> ingr;
public RecipeAda(Context ctx,HashMap<String, List<String>>recipes, List<String> ingr)
{
     this.ctx=ctx;
    this.recipes=recipes;
    this.ingr=ingr;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return recipes.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return recipes.get(ingr.get(groupPosition)).size();
}


@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return recipes.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int parent, int child) {
    return recipes.get(ingr.get(parent)).get(child);
}


@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}


@Override
public long getChildId(int parent, int child) {
    return child;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentview) {
    String grptit= (String) getGroup(parent);
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inf= (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inf.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout,parentview,false);
    }
    TextView pa= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    pa.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    pa.setText(grptit);
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public View getChildView(int parent, int child, boolean lastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parentview) {
    String childtitle= (String) getChild(parent,child);
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inf= (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inf.inflate(R.layout.child_layout,parentview,false);
    }
    TextView ch= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(exp_list);
    ch.setText(childtitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}}
```

It shows warning at the "groupPosition" in function definition of:

```
@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return recipes.get(groupPosition);
}
```

when hovered over it, says `HashMap<String, List<String>> may not contain objects of type 'integer'`
How do I correct this?
Also, how do I accept the contents(string) from the user and save in the database?

Comment: Your Hashmap uses String type as the key. But you're passing in an int to the get() method.

Comment: You can fix the warning by doing what you did in `getChildrenCount`.

Comment: As an aside, `Recipes` seems to be using `Movie...` components - I don't see a reference to `RecipeAda` anywhere. At least in terms of the domain, this doesn't seem right ...

Answer (score 2):

To create a HashMap it takes two things: a key and a type. To get the type(in your case a List) you need to pass a key(in your case a String). Meaning if you want to to `.get` with your current code you have to pass a string. If you want to use integers instead, simply change your hashmap to:

```
private HashMap<Integer, List<String>> recipes;
```

Alternatively, to `Integer.toString(id);` if you want to use Strings with numbers

> Also, how do I accept the contents from the user

Depends on what you mean by "accept the content". If you just mean passing a String into the hashmap you can just do `.put(id, "some string");`

> and save?

[External data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage),
 [Internal data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage),
 [SQL](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html),
 [SharedPrefs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)